# The system cannot infer the transport information from the mailto in WSO2 EI 6.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I've been trying to send the error message in the E-mail to send the E-mails I'm using the mailto function but when trying to invoke my API I got *The system cannot infer the transport information from the mailto error*. Please help me to sort this out.

```
<sequence name="ErrorSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<property expression="$ctx:token//*[local-name()='errorEmailRecipients']" name="errorEmailRecipients" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<property name="Subject" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Error While Processing Records"/>
<header expression="concat('mailto:', $ctx:errorEmailRecipients)" name="To" scope="default"/>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <root>
            <html>
                <body>
                    <p>There was an error While Processing Audio Record</p>
                    <p>Error Details: $1</p>
                </body>
            </html>
        </root>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ComsResponse"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
<call/>
<property action="remove" name="To" scope="transport"/>
```

[image: Log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable mailto transport sender with a set of working SMTP configurations? This needs to be done in axis2.xml if you are using WSO2 EI or deployment.toml if you are using MI.

Following is a sample config block in axis2.xml

```xml
<transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">synapse.demo.0</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">mailpassword</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">synapse.demo.0@gmail.com</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

Please refer [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/MailTo+Transport+#MailToTransport-enableMailToStep1:Enablingthetransportsender).